# Update user meta without lose of old data

Tags: user-meta

Is this is possible to update the user meta without lose the old data it have ?

For example :

i have the following data in my user meta field name `user_documents`

```
a:4:{i:0;s:36:"817fb3ec8e2412b141bcc40c1e16d4c9.jpg";i:1;i:91;i:2;s:27:"8769106-alone-wallpaper.jpg";i:3;i:92;}
```

this is about the attached files with the `user_documents` meta, if suppose a user upload more files i want to store it into the `user_documents` again but without lose the old meta which is above.

Comment: By default `add_user_meta` do not delete the old values. Check the last `$unique` parameter. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta

Comment: @M-R thanks for the comment, but the $unique parameter defines that it doesn't repeat the same `meta_key`, i want to update the `meta_value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand problem correctly, you want to store name of multiple files in user meta field. `add_user_meta` function has fourth argument `$unique` which is false by default that means for each call to `add_user_meta` a new key-value pair is added, even if key already exists.

[`add_user_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta) has less clarification then the [`add_post_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta) that does exactly same thing for posts. Here it says, how it works

> Note that if the given key already exists among custom fields of the
>   specified post, another custom field with the same key is added unless
>   the $unique argument is set to true, in which case, no changes are
>   made. If you want to update the value of an existing key, use the
>   update_post_meta() function instead.

So, you while uploading a file you will call `add_user_meta` with a new filename.

```
add_user_meta($user_id, 'user_documents','filename.txt');
```

Each time it will add a new pair, that can be fetched using [`get_user_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) function

```
get_user_meta($user_id, 'user_documents'); // set $single to false to fetch all values against 'user_documents' key.
```

It will return an array of all values stored against 'user_documents'.

To update a filename, you will need to provide filename against which you want to update.

```
update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_documents', 'filename.txt','new_filename.txt');
```

or you can delete a file by specifying the particular file name.

```
delete_user_meta($user_id, 'user_documents', 'filename.txt')
```

I hope, it clarifies how you would go for it.

Comment: let me try this, on before it if suppose there is more then one files on the meta value which stored as the json string, it will work or ?

Comment: Why do you want more than one file, json encoded, in one instance? Separating them would make them more managable and you dont need to json encode them.

Comment: So if we add new files by `add_user_meta` it will add new meta with the same key, and we can get everything together by `get_user_meta` ? is it ?

Comment: One more question about the delete, if i delete a meta with the specific file it doesn't work, because my `user_document` meta have the value like `a:2:{i:0;s:10:"sample.doc";i:1;i:105;}`, so it's deleting value, any guess ?

Comment: Sorry, I dont get your question `if i delete a meta with the specific file it doesn't work, ... so it's deleting value`.Btw, Why do you have to store it as a serialize array? I would recommend to convert it to a string. If you have to store "105", store it differently, may be, with separation of a special character.